# Is Presto Hive partition aware?

Tags: hive, presto

How does Presto deal with Hive partitions? can it recognize the partitions during the query execution? We are running into a performance issue while dealing with hive tables using partitions.

Answer (score 6):

Presto fully supports and optimizes queries to take advantage of Hive partitions. (It also optimizes queries over bucketed tables.) We use Hive partitioning extensively at Facebook (almost every table is at least partitioned by date), so support for Hive partitions was one of the first features we added.

If you are having a problem and need help troubleshooting, please ask on the mailing list as StackOverflow does not work well for back-and-forth discourse: https://groups.google.com/group/presto-users

Comment: I can confirm PrestoDB uses Hive partition very well.